# Некорректно работает поиск в элементах списка

Tags: python

Есть словарь для ведения телефонной книги. Нужно сделать функцию поиска в этой книге по нескольким цифрам номера телефона или буквам имени. В моём примере если я ищу "41", и в номере "41" стоит в конце номера - контакт не находит. В словаре ключ - это имя человека, а **значение - список** в котором может быть несколько номеров.

```
def find_contact(request):
    for name, phones in book.items():
        if request.lower() in name.lower() or any(request in phone for phone in phones):
            return f'Contact was found: {name} {book[name]}'
        else:
            return f'Your request was not found!'

book = {'Shahab': ['+421219842441']}
print(find_contact('41'))
```

Comment: вы попадаете в else при первой же неудаче. Надо писать, что не найдено, когда дошли до конца словаря

Comment: Спасибо, убрал else и теперь все работает.